# C# connectiong to oracle error - "The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client"

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle11g, 32bit-64bit, odac

I'm testing connection to my oracle db using 
Visual Studio 2012
Oracle 11g R2 Client 32-bit locally
Oracle 11g R2 Client 64-bit server
ODAC 11.2.0.320 32-bit

When I make the connection locally i'm able to get information to be returned from the database.  When I publish it on the server I keep getting "The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client".   Do I need 64-bit ODAC installed and using that Oracle.DataAccess.dll from there?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 32-bit client can talk to a 64-bit server, which is why it is working locally for you. When you publish to the server (I'm assuming ASP.NET) the ODP.NET versions must match exactly. E.g. you'll need to build locally against 64-bit ODP.NET if the server is 64-bit. Also ODP.NET is quite fussy about the version being exactly identical, so watch out for that.

Comment: sgrassie,  Thank you for the reply.   So do I need to install the 64-bit version ODAC on my local machine and use that dll?   All we have on the server is the client 11g R2.  Do I have to install ODAC as well separately?  Should I install the same 64-bit ODAC on both local and server?  Thanks

Comment: On your local machine it is working, so nothing is required there. But on your server you have to install the ODAC components in the same architecture (x64 / x86) and version as the 11g R2 client. You have to compile your project targetting to the same architecture as the server runs on.

Comment: On my local machine(x86) and Server (x64) have the same 11g R2 installed.  I'm not sure where to find the exact version.  I have installed ODAC 11.2 Release 5 and Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio (11.2.0.3.20) 32-bit on my local machine.  Now do I have to install the 64-bit version of ODAC 11.2 Release 5 on the server? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you have to install ODAC on your server according the version and architecture of the Oracle client on that server, so 11.2 (the minor Release should not matter). Check Registry `HKLM/Software/Oracle`. If it exists, its a x64 client, otherswise it is in `HKLM/Software/WOW6432Node/Oracle` for x86

Comment: I'm having issues with my network as soon as it's back up I will install the 64-bit version of the odac on the server and then test it out and post back my results.  Thank you

Comment: I did what you said and installed ODAC on the server. It seems to work.  Thank you again for all your help.